# Title page layout

Tags: titles

How can I get title page layout like this?

[image]

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package documentation.

Comment: please have a look at http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/TitlePages/titlepages.pdf   modify and use to your hearts content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this meets the requirement please tick the check mark on the left

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/jellyfish.tex
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE
    {\bfseries University of Water World\par}
    School of Atlantis\par
    \vspace{4cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Jellyfish -- Who needs them?\par}
    {\small Seriously}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \par
\end{center}
    \hfill\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \normalsize
        a funny thesis paper brought to you by\par
        \textsc{Carlos Pilkerton}\par
        Enjoy reading
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill

    \centering
    \today
\end{document}
```

Comment: please tick the check mark is meets the requirement--if anything else required put out in a comment