# Create thesis cover

Tags: thesis

I am trying to write a thesis from scratch. How can I develop a cover page like this?

[image]

This is my LateX source.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{
{Thesis Title}\\
{\large Institution Name}\\
{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{logo.png}}
}
\author{Author Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

\chapter*{Dedication}
To mum and dad

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Literature Review}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Methodology}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Discussion and Analysis}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum...

\appendix
\chapter{Questionnaire}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Regression Output}
Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

My code will result into something like this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Have you had a look around before asking? Please glance at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519192/title-page-layout

Comment: See also <https://www.oxfordechoes.com/oxford-thesis-template/>

Comment: Try using a `\documentclass{book}` environment for something closer to this look. `\documentclass{report/article}` will help too but then you have to play a little with the positioning of the logo and text on the title page. Also, for a thesis, I will always recommend a book environment, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

As @js bibra already pointed out, you can define your titlepage quite easily.

I'd suggest you should check the KOMA-Script classes.  Markus Kohm wrote `scrreprt` and `scrbook`as replacements for the standard LaTeX `report` and `book` classes.  I suggest it, because KOMA classes have very mighty commands, to create titlepages, including pretitle, dedications and lots more.  Have a look at the [english handbook](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), especially chapter 3.7.

In general, you can choose to use an predefined layout, which is generated by the command `\maketitle` or you could design your own titlepage environment by `begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}`.

Your thesis might start this

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% Definitions for the titles
%\titlehead{Not in use}
%\subject{Also not in use}
\title{Codimension-Two\\
  Free Boundary Problems}
\subtitle{School of Atlantis}
\author{
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}\\
  {\huge\bfseries Keith Gillow}\\
  St Catherine College\\
  University of Oxford}
\date{}
\publishers{A thesis submitted for the degree of\par 
  \textsc{Doctor of Philosphy}\\
  Trinity 1998\\[3ex]
  \today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Resulting in [image: KOMA-Script example titlepage]

Answer (score 2):

Does this meet the requirement?

Please tick the check mark on the left of the answer if meets the requirement--if anything else required put out in a comment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE
    {\bfseries Codimension-Two\\Free Boundary Problems\par}
    School of Atlantis\par
    \vspace{4cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}\\
    {\huge\bfseries Keith Gillow\par}
    {\small St Catherine College\\University of Oxford}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \par
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \normalsize\centering
        A thesis submitted for the degree of\par
        \textsc{Doctor of Philosphy}\par
        Trinity 1998
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \today
\end{center}
    \newpage
\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

\chapter*{Dedication}
To mum and dad

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Literature Review}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Methodology}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Discussion and Analysis}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Conclusion}
Lorem ipsum...

\appendix
\chapter{Questionnaire}
Lorem ipsum...

\chapter{Regression Output}
Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```